# Timeout download string message

Tags: c#

I use this script to download a string

```
public class TimedWebClient: WebClient
{
    public int Timeout { get; set; }

    public TimedWebClient()
    {
        this.Timeout = 600000; 
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var objWebRequest= base.GetWebRequest(address);
        objWebRequest.Timeout = this.Timeout;
        return objWebRequest;
    }
}


string s = new TimedWebClient {Timeout = 500}.DownloadString(URL);
```

But I want it to show a message if it timed out. Is this possible? Also this script makes the form inaccessible while loading and that's very annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `GetWebRequest()` will throw an exception if the request timeouted. You just need to catch the `WebException` that's being thrown there, e.g. by writing

```
try {
string s = new TimedWebClient {Timeout = 500}.DownloadString(URL);
}
catch(WebException e) {
Console.WriteLine("Some kind of exception has appeared! (Timeout / Resource not available)");
}
```

Also concerning your

> this script makes the form unaccesable while loading and thats verry annoying

problem, you should balance the downloading task into another thread to avoid that, so e.g. writing

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        //Download the resource in this new thread, same code as above
});
```

Notice that this uses the TLP library, so you'll need a

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

At the beginning of your program.

Comment: You are a legend man, this is the best answear i've ever had on stack overflow i wish that i could rep u but i cant because im new!